# ASP.net N tier Architecture presentation layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I meet a problem that I do not know how presentation layer use service layer. 
Totally I have three layers: data layer, service layer and presentation layer. 
In data layer I used Ado.net and created repository. 
In service layer I created Dto entities. 
And I meet a problem when I call service from Controller. 
The error is:

> No parameterless constructor was defined for this object.
>   Description: Unhandled exception when executing the current web request. Review the stack trace to see more information about this error and to determine where the error in the code was caused.
>   Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor has been defined for this object.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated while running the current web request. Information about the origin and location of the exception can be viewed using exception stacking.
>   
> Below is my code:

```
        using AutoMapper;
        using OA.Models;
        using OA.Service;
        using OA.Service.DAL;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Mvc;

        namespace OA.Controllers
        {
          public class HomeController : Controller
           {
              private readonly IUserService userService;
              private readonly IUserProfileService userProfileService;

          public HomeController(IUserService userService, IUserProfileService userProfileService)
          {
           this.userService = userService;
           this.userProfileService = userProfileService;
           }
    // GET: Home
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<UserViewModel> model = new List<UserViewModel>();
        userService.GetUsers().ToList().ForEach(u =>
        {
            UserProfileDto userProfileDto = userProfileService.GetUserProfile(u.Id);
            UserViewModel user = new UserViewModel
            {
                Id = u.Id,
                Name = $"{userProfileDto.FirstName} {userProfileDto.LastName}",
                Email = u.Email,
                Address = userProfileDto.Address
            };
            model.Add(user);
        });

        return View(model);
    }

  }
}
```

Does someone know what is the problem? Or I missunderstand how to use N tier achitecture? Thanks

Comment: Which object is throwing the exception? The message seems clear enough, have you tried to add a default (parameterless) constructor to that class?

Comment: Have you registered the parameters that you pass to the controller's constructor ( IUserService  and IUserProfileService) with your IoC provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register the `HomeController` in the IOC.

Exemple with Unity :

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<Controllers.HomeController>(new InjectionConstructor());
}
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks, I have fixed this problem